# Convert php loop to JavaScript

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, loops, while-loop

I would like to convert the following code from php to JavaScript:

```
$price = '270';

$allowed_sms_prices = array(
 5,7,10,15,20,25,30,35,39,40,
 45,49,50,55,59,60,69,75,79,85,
 89,95,100,125,150,175,200,225,250,275,
 300,310,315,320,325,330,335,340,345,350,
 355,360,365,370,375,380,385,390,395,400,
 405,410,415,420,425,430,435,440,445,450,
 455,460,465,470,475,480,485,490,495,500
);

while( ! in_array( $price, $allowed_sms_prices ) )
{
     $price = $price + 1;
}
echo $price;
```

Comment: If you'd have `$price = 501;` that would be an endless loop :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a javascript equivalent:

```
$price = 270;

$allowed_sms_prices = Array(
 5,7,10,15,20,25,30,35,39,40,
 45,49,50,55,59,60,69,75,79,85,
 89,95,100,125,150,175,200,225,250,275,
 300,310,315,320,325,330,335,340,345,350,
 355,360,365,370,375,380,385,390,395,400,
 405,410,415,420,425,430,435,440,445,450,
 455,460,465,470,475,480,485,490,495,500
);

while( $allowed_sms_prices.indexOf($price) == -1 )
{
     $price = $price + 1;
}
alert($price);
```

See how easy that was?

There is still a problem with your logic, namely that there is no reliable exit condition for the loop. For example, if the `$price` value was greater than `500`, the loop would run indefinitely. There are several approaches you could take that could correct this, one of which is to check if the value is not larger than the greatest value in the array.

Comment: @phpisuber01: `$` can be part of a variable name, if you want.

Comment: @phpisuber01 I just wanted to make the point that the changes that were required were minimal.

Comment: @azizpunjani That would be a correction of his logic. I am simply duplicating his logic in a different language.

Comment: @azizpunjani I have edited my answer to mention this concern, however.

Comment: It seems my hash technique is [little bit faster](http://jsperf.com/indexof-vs-array-hash)

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im By all means. My purpose here was to duplicate the asker's logic in javascript, not to correct it.

Comment: @Asad By all means, I wanted not only to change the logic to JS but also to provide better alternative.

Comment: Tedious and pedantic notes: `indexOf` on array instances isn't supported by IE(<9). Please, don't use `Array(1,3,4)` to instantiate a new array object, instead, use `[1,3,4]`. `$` _can_ be (part of) a variable name cf `$ === jQuery`, but the dollar, like the underscore sign was originally intended to be used for _"JS's internal affairs"_, or at least, that's what Douglas Crockford says

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I am aware of these things, this was just a joke answer, albeit an accurate one. Feel free to post one with the necessary style improvements and optimisations.

Comment: @Asad: I can't be bothered :P, it's just as a side-note, that might be of interest to the OP. The only thing I can't stand, though, is the (ab)use of the array constructor. I know you wanted the code to resemble the PHP code as much as possible, but PHP 5.4 now supports the `[]` array-notation, too. It also supports lambda functions and `json_decode` decodes to objects by default. It looks as if they're cherry-picking JS for the good parts :)